# Nginx - Setup subdomain doesn't work correctly

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, subdomain, debian-jessie

At beginning, I created a conf file that work correctly when I want to access to `http://www.domain.com` :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   root /var/www/domain;
   index index.html

   server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
}
```

Then I decide to create another conf file for a subdomain :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   root /var/www/subdomain.domain;
   index index.html

   server_name subdomain.domain.com;
}
```

Now the probleme is that whenever I want to access to `http://www.domain.com` or `http://subdomain.domain.com`, in both case the result is the page that I should obtain for the subdomain.

The new conf file is correctly added to `site-enabled` folder :

`ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/subdomain.domain.conf /etc/nginx/site-enabled/subdomain.domain.conf`

And this is how my DNS records looks like :

```
domain.com. IN A <server_ip>
www.domain.com. IN A <server_ip>
subdomain.domain.com. IN A <server_ip>
```

Comment: Why is there no semicolon in the  `index` directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `;` in the `index` directive, which causes nginx to interpret

```
index.html

server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
```

as the content of `index` directive. Therefore there is no virtual host defined with a `server_name`, and nginx will use the subdomain virtual host as the catch-all virtual host.

Comment: Arf, my bad, it was indeed the problem ... Thank you very much guys !